# Different behaviours of printing strings (sys.stderr.write) in Jupyter Notebook and Linux terminal

Tags: python, string, terminal, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

In Jupyter Notebook, when running the following Python codes, the number from 2 to 9 is printed, one after one. 
    import time

```
for i in range(1,10):
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stderr.write('\r %d' % i)
    sys.stderr.flush()
```

**<s>Q1: Why is 1 not printed?</s>**

**Q2: Why the numbers are printed one after one, I mean, when a larger number is printed, the immediate smaller number disappears (which is awesome)?** <s>Why `sys.stderr.write('\r %d' % i)` works in this way but `sys.stderr.write('%d \r' % i)` works in a "normal" way which displays all the numbers?</s>

When running the exact above codes in Linux terminal. The output is different again:

```
 13
 23
 33
 43
 53
 63
 73
 83
 93
```

If I change the line `sys.stderr.write('\r %d' % i)` to `sys.stderr.write('%d \r' % i)`, the output becomes:

```
3 
3 
3 
3 
3 
3 
3 
3 
3
```

This is so strange.

**Q3: Why running the above codes in Linux terminal has different output?**

Comment: I just tried your code in jupyter-notebook with a Python3 kernel and the 1 in fact got printed.

Comment: @timgeb Ok, you are right. I'm using the Jupyter Notebook integrated in PyCharm, maybe it has problems. I just tried the codes on web-based Jupyter Notebook, it indeed output 1. I'll rule out the 1st question.

Answer (score 0):

> Q1: Why is 1 not printed?

It did print though. Try a longer sleep.

> Q2: Why the numbers are printed one after one, I mean, when a larger number is printed, the immediate smaller number disappears (which is awesome)?

It's because you're using a carriage return `\r` instead of a linefeed `\n`, which returns the cursor to the start of the line, instead of advancing it to the next line. You can also overwrite things in the terminal using a backspace `\b` to move the cursor back one space.

> Q3: Why running the above codes in Linux terminal has different output?

I'm not sure which terminal you mean. Some terminals don't support overwrite, so the order you flush can affect the output.

Also, look at the docstring on the `write` method,

> write(s) method of idlelib.run.PseudoOutputFile instance
>       Write string to stream.
>       Returns the number of characters written (which is always equal to
>       the length of the string).

It returns the length of the string you passed in. In the Python shell (REPL), all return values get printed after the function returns. Try this in IDLE where stdin and stderr print in different colors:

```
>>> sys.stderr.write('x')
```

But look at what happens if you run this in a terminal,

```
>>> sys.stdout.write('abc\r')
4bc
```

First it prints `abc` then returns the cursor to the start of the line. Then it returns `4` because the string had len 4, so Python's REPL prints that at the cursor's current location, overwriting the `a`.

Comment: For Q3 in Ubuntu terminal, there is always a special number appended to each number when being printed. And it seems the special number is dependent on how many blankspace are there between `\r` and `%d`. When there is no blankspace, 1 blankspace, 2 blankspace, the special number is 2,3,4.